# boto3 clients and connections

Tags: session, boto, boto3

In boto2, you can close() connections after you finish with the client. How do you achieve the same with boto3

I want to have a DAO object taht looks like this:

```
class MyDAO:
    def __init__(self, mat_set, region):
        self.client = boto3.client('ec2' ... )

    def __enter__(self):
         return self

    def __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback):
         ## Clean up the connection of the client

def f():
    with MyDAO() as dao:
        ## Do some stuff
```

Comment: I guess a better question to ask is - Is this even needed? I searched all over the web and couldn't find people asking this question.

Comment: It isn’t needed:  https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2ps gave the answer - It isn't needed

https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/619